# Shopping Behavior Analysis is not showing data in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking, bigcommerce

I have connected my big-commerce site with google analytics E-commerce , but i am unable to view any data in "Shopping Behavior Analysis" section

[image: screenshot]

**Here is my site e-commerce tracking code**

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-25352625-2', 'duringdays.com.au');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

function trackEcommerce() {
this._addTrans = addTrans;
this._addItem = addItems;
this._trackTrans = trackTrans;
}
function addTrans(orderID,store,total,tax,shipping,city,state,country) {
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': orderID,
    'affiliation': store,
    'revenue': total,
    'tax': tax,
    'shipping': shipping,
    'city': city,
    'state': state,
    'country': country
});
}
function addItems(orderID,sku,product,variation,price,qty) {
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': orderID,
    'sku': sku,
    'name': product,
    'category': variation,
    'price': price,
    'quantity': qty
});
}
function trackTrans() {
    ga('ecommerce:send');
}
var pageTracker = new trackEcommerce();
   </script>
```

please any body let me know where i am wrong , i need to add any other code to track those information ?

thanks

Comment: were you able to solve this?